# How to transfer touch events to the view beneath in a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, events, touch, android-scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` on top of another view(with `Buttons`). The `ScrollView` is taking the whole screen and is obscuring the view that is beneath it.

At some point in my app I need the `ScrollView` to be disabled (but still visible) and transfer all the touch events to the `Buttons` that are beneath the `ScrollView`. How can I do that? Some views like `Buttons` are automatically doing that when disabled but a `ScrollView` is not doing that.

Comment: How do you disable the `ScrollView`? Also your situation seems a bit counter intuitive with the `ScrollView` still visible and `Buttons` getting clicked beneath it.

Comment: Its dificulte to explain the need for this behavior but thats what I need to do. all that I really need is the scroll view to be visible  but not intractable so all the touches will go to the layout beneath. is it posible?!
as for your question, I didn't disable the scroll view, that part of my problem, who should I disable it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to implement your own `ScrollView` which has a flag to indicate the status(disabled/enabled) and also overrides the `onTouchEvent` and `dispatchTouchEvent` to let the touch events get pass the `ScrollView`. Here is an example:

```
public class DisabledScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private boolean mIsDisable = false;

    // if status is true, disable the ScrollView
    public void setDisableStatus(boolean status) {
        mIsDisable = status;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // no more tocuh events for this ScrollView
        if (mIsDisable) {
            return false;
        }       
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // although the ScrollView doesn't get touch events , its children will get them so intercept them.
        if (mIsDisable) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

}
```

Then all you have to do is change the value of that flag. See if it works.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I just needed to handle the touch event in View A, which was overlaping View B and then send the event to View B. Both views were child of the same RelativeLayout, but there was no parent-child relation between views A and B. This worked for me:

```
viewA.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          // do my stuff here

          viewB.dispatchTouchEvent( event );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I have a recyclerview under a scrollview. The top of scrollview is in vertical scroll, and the recyclerview is in horizontal scroll. The scrollview have top padding, making the recyclerview is visible through the transparency in the scrollview padding. I have to make it this way because when the scrollview is scrolled the recyclerview will scroll vertically to like parallax effect (this effect is in another code). This code below is working for my case, might help

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        float mDownX,mDownY;
        boolean mIsSwiping,isDown;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(mIsSwiping){
                recyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            }
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mIsSwiping = false;
                    isDown = true;
                    mDownX = event.getX();
                    mDownY = event.getY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if(isDown){
                        float deltaX = Math.abs(event.getX() - mDownX);
                        float deltaY = Math.abs(event.getY() - mDownY);
                        mDownX = event.getX();
                        mDownY = event.getY();
                        if(deltaX!=deltaY){
                            isDown = false;
                            if(deltaX>deltaY){
                                mIsSwiping = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

            return mIsSwiping;
        }
    });
```

This is the layout

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/gray0"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:paddingBottom="70dp">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="301.75dp"
    android:paddingBottom="23.5dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">
```

.
.
.